# Third 3D coordinate of right angle triangle

Tags: 3d, coordinates, trigonometry, missing-data, plane

For a right angle triangle in 3D space, if I have

1. Hypotenuse start and end 3D coordinates
2. 3D plane definition
3. **Lengths of two sides (other that hypotenuse) known**

How can I calculate the 3rd 3D coordinate?

Answer (score 0):

Upon some more study on my question again ... found that Thales' theorem suit for my question and there wouldn't be only one solution.
**But if I know length of two sides, then probably answers could to two possible coodinates. But, Not sure how to find that 3rd coordinate**. Please advise if way out

Comment: So, if you found a solution, please write it here: this is a reference site (not a forum), so your question is supposed to help other people

Comment: Please don't use answers to ask a new/follow-on question or focus an existing one.

Comment: Noted. Thank you Greybeard.

Answer (score 0):

Based on intersection of two circles on same plane, we can find those points

Refer...
[Circle-circle intersection in 3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35748840/circle-circle-intersection-in-3d#35751516)

And related code
https://gist.github.com/herzig/cc5833f6b4b4c0ac1e314bb16cb94dc3